# Blood on Right Earlobe, Right Thumb, and Right Big Toe

Tags: kohen-priest, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, parts-of-the-body, blood, tzaraas-negaim

There is a ritual in the Bible in which blood from a sacrifice is applied to the right earlobe, right thumb, and right big toe of people. The ritual is done for Aaron and his sons during their onboarding ceremony so to speak, and the ritual is done for a leper (someone with tzara'at) once they turn completely white.

Leviticus 8:23-24;

> and it was slaughtered. Moses took some of its blood and put it on the
> ridge of Aaron’s right ear, and on the thumb of his right hand, and on
> the big toe of his right foot.  Moses then brought forward the sons of
> Aaron, and put some of the blood on the ridges of their right ears,
> and on the thumbs of their right hands, and on the big toes of their
> right feet; and the rest of the blood Moses dashed against every side
> of the altar.

Leviticus 14:14

> The priest shall take some of the blood of the guilt offering, and the
> priest shall put it on the ridge of the right ear of the one who is
> being purified, and on the thumb of the right hand, and on the big toe
> of the right foot.

What is the significance of this ritual? Do any commentaries discuss why the same ritual is done for the all white leper and for the priests?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Ohr_Sameach_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Offerings_for_Those_with_Incomplete_Atonement.5.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: What does you mean, "all white leper"?